# Embedable Widgets in ASP.Net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, widget

We have a existing ASP.Net webforms application which is used by a lot of external clients. 
eg: property.onesite.realpage.com\ol2\?s=1008641. Select a apartment type and click search. 
I have been tasked with creating html, css, javascript widgets of certain core functionality(eg: Search apartments and show apartment results in the example above) so 
a. external clients can host it in their applications like this on thier html page.

```
<DIV id="searchwidget">
     <script src="http://property.onesite.realpage.com/widgets/search.js"/>
</DIV>
```

b. We can embed the same widgets into our new internal applications. We are planning to build a new ASP.Net MVC application for this. 
c. Embed the same widgets into our old ASP.Net webforms applications.

How do we take care of communication(passing request data) between 
a. different widgets,
b. widgets and the container application

How do we store the state of the widgets? I am sure I have other questions but I am not sure if I am asking the questions that I need to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at how other Shared scripts work. For e.g Google Maps, there is always a unique key appended in the query string. this key can be used to identify the client.

I created one which involved showing customized weather conditions. I implemented token based request using Jquery and rest based WCF services.